# In Windows 11 and server 2022, the child dialog in my MFC application does not display the maximize and Restore buttons properly

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-10, windows-11, windows-server-2022

[image]

If we see above in the image, we would not be able to see the Maximize and Restore button, but I would tell that Maximize button is hidden behind the icon and there is a restore button on the left. Below is the image after moving this minimized window to from top left to somewhere in the middle of the screen.

[image]

If you see the image above we are able to see that there is restore button too, but since it is outside the boundary of the minimized title bar so we are not able to click it.

And the funny thing is that this issue is only in Windows 11 and Windows server 2022, in all other windows it works properly.

I have even tried changing the Windows Metrics in Registry for Windows 2022 to match my Windows 10 still no luck.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: This is a non-standard title bar, the result of executing custom code. Since the issue is with high probability in that custom code, it would help to see a [mcve].